# One word-count per line

Tags: c, word-count

Looking for pseudo code to help me figure this question out:

After processing the text file into your concordance you will print all of the words and their counts. Print one word-count pair per line.

So if the text file had two "and"s it would print and:2, not and:1, and:2.

```
count = 1;
if (*value > 1){ //finds all words repeated at least once
    count++;
printf("%s:%d\n, word, count):
```

??

Comment: Well, have a shot at it, what steps would you take to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not big enough, you can store each word of the file in a hashtable which would store words as keys and their count as values. If there is a hash collision or the word is already in hash table, increment count else keep on adding new words into hash.